# Display All MessageBox in Program with TimeStamp method

Tags: c#, winforms, timestamp, messagebox

Is there a way I can programatically set all MessageBoxes with a timestamp tacked on the end of the msg string.

```
private string DataTimeMsgBox()
{
    return DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
MessageBox.Show("Cannot Pass An Empty Textbox" + " " + DataTimeMsgBox());
```

Above Is not what I'm looking for, but this is

```
MessageBox.Show("Message with timestamp")
```

Result:

```
"Message with timestamp 00/0000/00 12:00"
```

Comment: I don't understand, what do you want as a result?

Comment: "Message with timestamp 00/0000/00 12:00" should be result, but timestamp needs to be concatenated to all messageboxes without actually coding "Messagebox message + DateTime.Now.ToString())

Comment: Extend MessageBox and override the show method to make every message end with a timestamp

Comment: You could replace all calls to MessageBox.Show(msg) with your own function, ShowMyMessageBox(msg), and append the timestamp to the message.

Comment: Steve can you show me or point me in the right direction how to do that

Comment: pspet but every message box will be different

Comment: @CSharper you want to paste time stamp on every message box in the system (outside of your application)?

Comment: its a local junk c# winforms app

Comment: @CSharper if so, the solutions below should work for you, at least they're the simplest solutions. If you want a real custom `MessageBox`, you may have to write much code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your own helper method:

```
private void ShowMessage(string message)
{
    MessageBox.Show(message + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
}
```

Call this method instead of calling MessageBox.Show.

Comment: yep thats it! just thought about doing that myself

Comment: Although I would extend the parameter to the ones of MessageBox.Show(...) respectively create multiple methodes with different parameters

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
public static class CustomMessageBox {
  public static void Show(string message) {
    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0} {1}", message, DateTime.Now.ToString()));
  }
}
```

Then all you'd have to do is search through your solution for every instance of `MessageBox` and replace it with `CustomMessageBox`.